# How can I use pandas .head() function for multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl

I would like to examine the head of the dataframes below at the same, without repeating `.head()` 3x.

```py
ride_sharing = pd.read_csv('datasets/ride_sharing_new.csv', index_col = 'Unnamed: 0')
airlines = pd.read_csv('datasets/airlines_final.csv',  index_col = 'Unnamed: 0')
banking = pd.read_csv('datasets/banking_dirty.csv', index_col = 'Unnamed: 0')
```

The solution I am using is this one:

```py
print(ride_sharing.head(), airlines.head(), banking.head())
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
dataframes = [ride_sharing, airlines, banking]

for df in dataframes:
    print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-loop to iterate over the data frames.

```
for df in (ride_sharing,  airlines, banking):
    print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
files = ['datasets/ride_sharing_new.csv', 'datasets/airlines_final.csv', 'datasets/banking_dirty.csv']
dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = 'Unnamed: 0') for filename in files]
[print(df.head()) for df in dfs]
```